# Custom error pages on Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, custom-errors

I'm running an Apache Tomcat server with 2 custom servlets. The tree structure looks like:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/
         ROOT/
           WEB-INF/
         servlet1/
           META-INF/
           WEB-INF/
         servlet2/
           META-INF/
           WEB-INF/
```

I am trying to add a custom error html page for each servlet that will be displayed on error 400, 404 and when there is an exception on the servlet (such as the information that was supposed to be sent to the servlet on the http request is not there)

I added to `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/servlet1/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
 <error-page>
   <error-code>400</error-code>
   <location>/error.html</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/error.html</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
   <location>/error.html</location>
 </error-page>
```

and I created `error.html` in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/`. This doesn't seem to be working. When I type" `www.server.com/servlet1/SomRandomStuff` to get a 404, a blank page is displayed, not error.html. Something else happens when I call the servlet without passing the correct info to it, the browser will ask me if i want to download a file.
I've tried placing `error.html` not on `ROOT` but on the servlet1 directory. Didn't work. I checked that `error.html` has the correct permissions, it is OK. I am out of ideas and the few tutorials I found online are very vague.

What am I doing wrong? How do I achieve this - display a custom error page per servlet?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your page paths starting with slashes:

```
 <error-page>
   <error-code>400</error-code>
   <location>**/error.html**</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>**/error.html**</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
   <location>**/error.html**</location>
 </error-page>
```

In this case it might be looking for them in the root of the drive.

If they are in the same folder as web.xml you can try it this way **`./error.html`**

Other than that, I would recommend trying the full path to the file: **`/var/www/error/error.html`** or whatever your situation is.

Comment: Eli, thank you. It is still showing the same behavior, even when I put the full path to error.html

Comment: Ok. I managed to make it work for standard html errors (400, 404, etc). I just needed to place the error.html in the correct location. Now for the servlet being called without arguments: it still offers me to download it. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your directory settings, it is skipping my mind right now, but there is essentially a directive command which has to be changed in order to "open in browser" not "download" files

Comment: Thanks again but I am working blind right now since I have no idea where to even begin looking

Comment: I'm trying a few things, but here is a good beginner tutorial on servlets that may possibly help get you headed in the right direction: http://cs.calstatela.edu/~abbott/Courses/CS_320b/Running%20a%20Servlet%20under%20Tomcat.html

Comment: Yes... not really helped. I asked a [separate question](http://serverfault.com/questions/254162/prevent-downloading-of-the-servlet-in-apache-tomcat) since no one seems to know how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

to capture 404 for `www.server.com/servlet1/SomRandomStuff` move your error.html file to `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/servlet1/error.html`. copy the error file to each of your webapp. Even though not the best way to handle this, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your error file should sit in this directory (not root):

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/servlet1
```